# Less number of individuals returned using SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, owl, ontology

I have an [ontology](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wndo58dgj7n6glw/demoontCreate.owl?dl=0) and I am interested in the classes shown in below figure:

[image]

I have created two individuals of Observation class (i.e., observation1 and observation2) and hence accordingly two individuals of other classes (sensoroutput, observationvalue) as shown in below:

```
<!-- http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Observation1 -->
       <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Observation1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&j.3;Observation"/>
        <j.3:observationResult rdf:resource="&j.3;SensorOutput1"/>
        <j.3:observedBy rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Co2Sensor_Diningroom"/>
        <j.3:observationSamplingTime rdf:resource="&j.2;Instant1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

     <!-- http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Observation2 -->
         <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Observation2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&j.3;Observation"/>
        <j.3:observationResult rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput2"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

     <!-- http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue1 -->
     <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&j.3;ObservationValue"/>
        <j.1:hasRegionDataValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;decimal">216.56</j.1:hasRegionDataValue>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

     <!-- http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue2 -->
     <Owl: NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&j.3;ObservationValue"/>
        <j.1:hasRegionDataValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">121212</j.1:hasRegionDataValue>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

     <!-- http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput1 -->
     <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Co2SensorOutput"/>
        <j.3:hasValue rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

     <!-- http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput2 -->
         <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Co2SensorOutput"/>
        <j.3:hasValue rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue2"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Now when I use SPARQL to get observationValues associated with two observations I used to get only values associated with observation2 and nothing is obtained about observation1. Sparql query is:

```
PREFIX ssn: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#>
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dul: <http://www.loa-cnr.it/ontologies/DUL.owl#>
      SELECT  ?x ?r ?val
       WHERE
        { ?x  rdf:type ssn:Observation.
          ?x  ssn:observationResult ?d.
          ?d ssn:hasValue ?r.
          ?r dul:hasRegionDataValue ?val.
        }
```

I want to know where I am doing wrong and why only one(i.e., observation2 and not observation1) individual is returned?

Comment: Your data sample is incomplete (missing root elements and namespace declarations), which makes it hard to try and reproduce the problem. Please make sure that when asking these kinds of questions, you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I have shown only relevant part of ontology. At the begining of question I have provided link to my full ontology. Here again I am provding link to full ontology as [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wndo58dgj7n6glw/demoontCreate.owl?dl=0)

Comment: I'm sorry but a  link to your full ontology is really not good enough for this kind of thing. It is a requirement that all necessary info is present _in the question itself_ here on SO. Have a look at that link to the help section I provided, it explains in detail why you should always try and create an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your file. Your instances are somehow named differently at different locations. To get your query working, rename the individual `&j.3;SensorOutput1` on line *1581* with the full uri: `http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput1`. To be more specific:

**Line 1581**

Change this:

```
<j.3:observationResult rdf:resource="&j.3;SensorOutput1"/>
```

To this:

```
<j.3:observationResult rdf:resource="http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#SensorOutput1"/>
```

---

Given the above changes, the query returns:

```
x | r | val

<http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Observation2> <http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue2> "121212"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>

<http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#Observation1> <http://www.iiitd.edu.in/~haroonr/ontologies/DGO#ObservationValue1> 216.56
```

Don't forget to type correctly the primitive values in your data i.e. `216.56` is typed as decimal, while `121212` is typed as String.

Answer (score 2):

`Observation1` does not match your query because its value for `ssn:observationResult`, (`ssn:SensorOutput1`) does not have an `ssn:hasValue` property. Hence, only `Observation2` is returned as a result.